# Vue-CLI v3 app: hot module reload not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I've installed Vue CLI v3, and in my terminal:

- created a new app using 'vue create my-project' (accepting default config)
- navigated to the 'my-project' app directory and run 'npm run serve', the result of which is:

> ```
> DONE Compiled successfully in 11889ms
>
> App running at:
> - Local: http://localhost:8080/
> - Network: http://192.168.0.3:8080/
>
> Note that the development build is not optimized. To create a production build, run npm run build.
> ```

... and then, when making any change whatsoever to the Hello World component, e.g., a tweak to the css, something obvious like the link color, nothing happens; no response in the terminal, no browser refresh, and *no update to the page when manually refreshing*.

I've built a few apps using Vue in the past, hot module reloading was working previously, but now there is zero activity/response in the terminal regardless of what I change in any project file; only if I close the terminal tab, re-open a tab, navigate to the project directory and re-run 'npm run serve', and refresh the browser do I see the changes. obviously this is unusable. What am I missing?

Comment: What's your environment? (platform? and versions of node, npm, vue-cli, and browser?) Any console logs?

Comment: Does not seem, that you are doing something wrong by what you are describing in your question. You need to debug and/or give more information. I would try to reinstall npm/yarn, reinstalling all npm/yarn modules & `vue-cli`. Did you uninstall a possible previous `vue-cli` installation? Maybe try to run it on a different port. And check your firewall config, if anything was blocked, etc.

Comment: @tony19 Thank you for your help (and please pardon my tardy response)

OS X Yosemite
node v10.8.0
npm v6.2.0
vue v3.0.1
Chrome v68

... and no, since nothing at all happens in my console upon file changes, I have no error logs. And yes, according to the docs on vue-cli v3, I did uninstall previous vue-cli and had to update node. No changes to firewall, nothing pertinent blocked. If this doesn't suggest anything to either of you then I suppose I can try to reinstall all this.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3

Thank you for your help (and please pardon my tardy response) OS X Yosemite node v10.8.0 npm v6.2.0 vue v3.0.1 Chrome v68 ... and no, since nothing at all happens in my console upon file changes, I have no error logs. And yes, according to the docs on vue-cli v3, I did uninstall previous vue-cli and had to update node. No changes to firewall, nothing pertinent blocked. If this doesn't suggest anything to either of you then I suppose I can try to reinstall all this

Comment: Do you have any extensions that are blocking the hot module updates? Try opening Chrome with all extensions disabled. You can do that by: (1) close all Chrome instances, (2) run `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-extensions --bwsi --incognito`

Comment: thanks @tony19 I tried this too, no luck. fwiw, chrome console shows:

[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...log.js?1afd:24 

so I wonder if something is funky in my webpack install (which I've updated too, and haven't touched any config) . as far as I know vue-cli 3 ought to have HMR out of the box

Comment: Did you make any modifications to the vue-cli generated project? You shouldn't have to reinstall any dependencies once the project is generated. Why does `npm run serve` take ~12s? That's unusually long (it should be ~3s).

Comment: No @tony19 I hadn't made any mods to the project. And as to why npm run serve takes ~12s, well I guess my machine is getting old and slow ;) ... p.s. please see my Answer below (and thank you again)

Comment: For others looking into this (or similar problems), try looking at what's up on port 8081. If 8080 is in use it'll go +1 to 8081. Fixing it depends on what's listening on port 8080.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been resolved, though I am not 100% sure what caused it.

I noticed that some people with similar failures of hot reload had mentioned bad directory names. My vue project's parent directory name was legit but I had renamed it at one point (though that was multiple restarts and reinstalls ago), and I also noticed that some of the vue-cli-created project folders were not displaying in the Finder until it was quit and restarted. I figured there was something corrupted about that folder. I created a new folder - a sibling of the dubious folder - and had another go with vue-cli, and it worked as expected.

Hope this helps someone. Thanks again to those of you who offered suggestions.

Whiskey T.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using WSL. I ran into this exact problem and solved it via this method.

> I had the same issue, It seems wsl2 does not watch for file changes
> inside the windows filesystem. Everything works fine if the vue
> project is inside the Ubuntu filesystem. Check out this link for
> further info
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-ux-changes.

Source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4421#issuecomment-557194129

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with different capitalization between the folder name and router/index.js file.

My folder was name `views/account/Login.vue`

The router/index.js had `import Login from '../views/Account/Login.vue';`

The file would load correctly on `npm run dev` but would not hot reload when it was changed.

Changing the import to `import Login from '../views/account/Login.vue';` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If u installed Node js as `sudo`, then Running `sudo npm run serve` worked for me. Actually `node.js` was installed as `sudo` and the project also created as `sudo` so when I run `npm run serve` the `vue-hot-reload-api` cannot access the node server to do hot reload

Additionally if u want the hot reload to work in offline mode, then switch off your network and then `npm run serve`  and then reconnect to your network. That will work as localhost protocol and not use your local network IP.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for posting this Jose. I'm not an expert but my understanding is that it might be preferred generally to avoid using sudo when installing via npm or other package managers, but perhaps it is required for some devs. Anyway I hope your post is helpful to others, and thanks for the tip re: offline mode. Cheers!

Comment: Why voted me down? Any violation of Stackoverflow reason? Please explain!

Answer (score 0):

Add following script tag to package.json file

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development vue-cli-service serve --open --host localhost",
     ....
  },
....
```

and run with

```
npm install –save-dev cross-env

npm run dev
```

source: https://www.davidyardy.com/blog/vue-cli-creating-a-project%E2%80%93issue-with-hot-reload/